# Query for first row of choice

Tags: sql

I was trying to build a query which will return all the rows but first row of my choice.

Example:-

Table

```
ID     Type       Name
1      Fruit      Apple
2      Fruit      Orange
3      Veg        Broccoli
4      Fruit      Banana
5      Fruit      Grape
6      Fruit      Kiwi
```

Now, query should return list of fruits but Banana on top. Result should be

```
Banana
Apple
Grape
Kiwi
Orange
```

Thank You!

Comment: Maybe provide us the query you have so far?

Comment: *Why* should Banana be the first record? Must Apple be the second record? If so, why?

Comment: Yes -- "banana on top" suggests a sort criterion, but what is it?

Comment: ALSO, the answer may depend partly on which database management program you are using.

Comment: -1 for inadequate information and apparent research.  I can happily take away my down-vote if the post is improved.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
select name
from t
where type = 'Fruit'
order by (case when name = 'Banana' then 1 else 0 end) desc, name
```